# Group by and then select based on those group values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Basically I'm doing some work to fill a datatable.  Then once I had that datatable, I'm going my results.  Then What I want to do is select from my original datatable based off those results.  The code I have below is failing so any help would be fantastic. The second part i'm curious of, is how to I return a collection to iterate for the select

Thanks!

```
DataTable invoicesDataTable = null;
try
{
    invoicesDataTable = GetInvoiceIds();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

//new work here
var uniqueCountryCustomer = 
    invoicesDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new
        {
            Department = (string)row["Department"], 
            Attorney = (string)row["MatterNumber"], 
            MatterNo = (string)row["CUSTOMERNAME"]
        });

string depart = string.Empty;
string attorn = string.Empty;
string MatNo = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray().Length; i++)
{
    var results =
        from myRow in invoicesDataTable.AsEnumerable()
        where myRow.Field<string>("Department") == uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i].ToString() 
            && myRow.Field<string>("MatterNumber") == uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i].ToString() 
            && myRow.Field<string>("CUSTOMERNAME") == uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i].ToString()
        select myRow;
    //now do work on each of these rows from the group
}
```

Comment: The `GroupBy` looks strange. Usually you select a particular property to group on. Then you can use a projection (`Select`) to aggregate properties into a new type.

Comment: @Kryptos actually the group by works perfectly, what i'm not sure of is teh where part , uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i] doesn't work

Comment: First of all. Don't call `ToArray()` multiple times. Call it just after `GroupBy()`. Otherwise you will end-up doing the enumeration multiple times.

Comment: @Mike The reason `uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i]` is not working is because that returns a type of `IGrouping`.  You would need to compare the field to the group's key, which is itself, an anonymous type with `Department`, `Attorny` and `MatterNo` properties.  So `myRow.Field<string>("Department") == uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i].Key.Department`.

Comment: And @Krypto is right all those calls to `ToArray()` are not good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with datatables... ever, really.  But can you not do this:

```
DataTable invoicesDataTable = null;
try
{
    invoicesDataTable = GetInvoiceIds();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

//new work here
var uniqueCountryCustomer = 
    invoicesDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new
    {
        Department = (string)row["Department"], 
        Attorney = (string)row["MatterNumber"], 
        MatterNo = (string)row["CUSTOMERNAME"]
    });

foreach(var customerGroup in uniqueCountryCustomer)
{
    foreach(var row in customerGroup)
    {
        //now do work on each of these rows from the group
    }
}
```

Is there some reason you need to get the row from the table again after the grouping?

Comment: Jason - I need to some and write out the rows based on specific criteria afterwards

Comment: Why not just add a where clause to the LINQ statement?

Answer (score 1):

The GroupBy has three parts:
1) Select the key
2) Select the values
3) How to project key/values

Fairly good examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534493(v=vs.100).aspx

```
var uniqueCountryCustomer = 
    invoicesDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(Key => new
    {
        Department = (string)row["Department"], 
        Attorney = (string)row["MatterNumber"], 
        MatterNo = (string)row["CUSTOMERNAME"]
    },Vals => new {
        something1 = ...,
        something2 = ...
    },(Key,Vals)=>new {
        Key=Key,
        Sum=vals.Select(v=>v.something1).Sum(),
        //If you need these
        Max=vals.Select(v=>v.something1).Max(),
        Min=vals.Select(v=>v.something1).Min(),
        Vals=Vals
    });

foreach(var customer in uniqueCountryCustomer)
{
     ... Do stuff ...
     Console.Writeline("Customer {0} owes us a total of {1}",customer.Key.MatterNo,customer.Sum);
     foreach(var things in customer)
     {
        Console.Writeline("...Bill:{0}",var.something1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Seems odd that you are mapping MatterNumber to Attorney and CUSTOMERNAME to MatterNo.  Did you accidentally reverse these?

Comment: Very cool.  Apparently, I have not given `GroupBy` enough love because I was not aware of this overload.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this code that fails:

```
var results =
    from myRow in invoicesDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    where myRow.Field<string>("Department") == uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i].ToString() 
        && myRow.Field<string>("MatterNumber") == uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i].ToString() 
        && myRow.Field<string>("CUSTOMERNAME") == uniqueCountryCustomer.ToArray()[i].ToString()
    select myRow;
```

You compare each field with the same value which can't be right.

Maybe you can replace `ToString()` with `Department` and so on? Those values you used in your `GroupBy` expression?!